# bash expression for filenames with two or more date ranges

Tags: bash

I am trying to perform operations on a group of log files in unix. The operation is copy.

Let's say I want to copy last weeks log files (January 25th-31st) from the current directory to another directory and those files have names like:

```
 log-20150125, log-20150126, ..., log-20150131
```

I tried the following in bash:

```
 cp (log-201501)|2[5-9]|3[0-1]*.gz /home/user/bin/Temp
```

and got an error that says "syntax error near unexpected token log-201501"

I think I'm doing something wrong. What is the expression for capturing two date ranges?

Comment: that's shell pathname expansion (with wildcards). it doesn't follow regex rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash has a lot of syntax, so you can't just throw parentheses and pipes around willy-nilly

```
shopt -s extglob
cp log-201501@(2[6-9]|3[0-1])*.gz /home/user/bin/Temp
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching

If that's too incomprehensible, split it up

```
cp log-2015012[6-9]*.gz log-2015013[0-1]*.gz /home/user/bin/Temp
```

or brace expansion is nicely readable

```
cp log-201501{26,27,28,29,30,31}*.gz /home/user/bin/Temp
```

Comment: You sir are my hero! I am still a novice in unix and this helped me tremedously thank you!